# In my php program i am using an Array called $COL_array[] , its not working the second time in select?

Tags: php, html, arrays, select, html-select

I can't seem to add the `$COL_array` in the second select option. Why not?
I am using two selection options that are reading back the array and second section option is not calling the array back?

```
<tr>
    <td><br><p>Location A:</td> //
    <td><select>
        <?php
        $key1 = '';
        while (list ($key1, $val1) = each($COL_array)  ){
            echo "<option value ='$key1'>$key1</option>";
        }

        ?>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>

<td><br><p>Wages in Location A :</td> <td> $ <input type="text" name="wage " >
<tr>
    <td><br><p>Location B:</td>
    <td><select>
        <?php
        $key = '';
        while (list ($key, $val2) = each($COL_array)  ){
            echo"<option value ='$key'> </option>";
        }

        ?>``


    </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i suggest a foreach loop

Comment: Yeah but the thing is it works on the first select option why not working again on the second selection option?

Answer (score 0):

Because `each` advances the array cursor, you'll need to

```
reset($COL_array);
```

between the loops to move the cursor back to the beginning.

[From the PHP manual for `each`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php):

> After each() has executed, the array cursor will be left on the next element of the array, or past the last element if it hits the end of the array. You have to use reset() if you want to traverse the array again using each.